# ParameterGrid splits the string instead of combination

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm trying to get the parameter grid for model selection. So, following the example in [Sklearn documentation about ParameterGrid function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html) we have this:

```
param_grid = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [True, False]}
list(ParameterGrid(param_grid)) == (
                [{'a': 1, 'b': True}, {'a': 1, 'b': False},
                 {'a': 2, 'b': True}, {'a': 2, 'b': False}])
```

But what I want is pass only one value, without using list annotation ([]), like this:

```
param_grid = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': 'True', 'c': 'something'}
```

But then, `list(ParameterGrid(param_grid))` just split all the strings instead of creation of two combinations. Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 'T', 'c': 's'}
{'a': 1, 'b': 'T', 'c': 'o'}
{'a': 1, 'b': 'T', 'c': 'm'}
```

The question is, it's required to put all items in list format, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `[]` notation, because the `ParameterGrid` expects the values to be an iterable. So when you set `b` as

```
'b': 'True'
```

It will iterate over the string `'True'`, hence you are getting different combinations with T, R, U and E.

To fix this, use it like this

```
param_grid = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [True], 'c': ['something']}
```